# Uploading video file to server but gets posted in bytes

Tags: iphone, ios

Trying to post the video file to server, getting posted in bytes. Posting my code below i am using for posting.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
NSString* mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
if ( [mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie" ])
{        
    if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0)
        == kCFCompareEqualTo)
    {

        NSURL *videoUrl=(NSURL*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        NSData *webData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoUrl];
        [self post:webData];

        if([profile isEqualToString:@"friend"])
        {
            [self callServerFriend];
        }
        if([profile isEqualToString:@"public"])
        {
            [self callServerPublic];
        }
    }
 }    

- (void)post:(NSData *)fileData
{
NSLog(@"POSTING");

index1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"videoName"];
valIndex1 = index1;
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"video_%d.mp4",valIndex];

// Generate the postdata:
NSData *postData = [self generatePostDataForData: fileData];

profileImg = profilePic;

NSArray *arrImg = [profileImg componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *strImg1 = [arrImg objectAtIndex:[arrImg count]-2];
NSString *strImg2 = @"/";
NSString *strImg3 = [arrImg lastObject];
//NSLog(@"img2-----------------%@",strImg2);
NSString *pImg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",strImg1, strImg2, strImg3];
NSLog(@"img-----------------%@",pImg);

// Setup the request:

NSString *urlString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myvnt.co/overheadPost.php?userId=%@&type=Video&text=%@&image=%@&location=%@&Upload=Upload", uid, statusPost, pImg, locc]stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *wigiRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:30.0];
[wigiRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// just some random text that will never occur in the body
NSString *stringBoundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY---This_Is_ThE_BoUnDaRyy---pqo";

// header value
NSString *headerBoundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",
                            stringBoundary];

// set header
[wigiRequest addValue:headerBoundary forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

//add body
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
NSLog(@"body made");

//IMAGE Posting

[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
//"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileUpload\";filename=\"" + imagePath + "\"" + lineEn

//[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileUpload\"; filename=\"img.mp4\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileUpload\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", str]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithCString:"--AaB03x\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadFile\"; filename=\"img.mp4\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

// Get the post header int ASCII format:
NSData *postHeaderData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

// Generate the mutable data variable:
postData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:[postHeaderData length] ];
//[postData setData:postHeaderData];

// add it to body
[postBody appendData:postData];
[postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// final boundary
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// add body to post
[wigiRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];

NSLog(@"body set");
// pointers to some necessary objects
NSHTTPURLResponse* response =[[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] init];
NSError* error = [[NSError alloc] init] ;


// synchronous filling of data from HTTP POST response
NSData *respData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:wigiRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSLog(@"just sent request");

NSString *responseHTML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[respData bytes]
                                                  length:[respData length]
                                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"response dictionary : %@",responseHTML);

index1++;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:index forKey:@"videoName"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}

- (NSData *)generatePostDataForData:(NSData *)uploadData
{
// Generate the post header:
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithCString:"--AaB03x\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadFile\"; filename=\"img.mp4\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

// Get the post header int ASCII format:
NSData *postHeaderData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

// Generate the mutable data variable:
NSMutableData *postData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:[postHeaderData length] ];
[postData setData:postHeaderData];

// Add the image:
[postData appendData: uploadData];

// Add the closing boundry:
[postData appendData: [@"\r\n--AaB03x--" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];

// Return the post data:
return postData;
}
```

And another thing is it posting the video with the same name every time so every new post replace the previous one. But the main issue is why it posting in bytes i am not getting that.
Please guide for above. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I've stored it with current Date-Time ::

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    NSString *type = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if ([type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeVideo] || [type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
    {
        videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

        NSLog(@"found a video");

        // Code To give Name to video and store to DocumentDirectory //

        videoData = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL] retain];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy||HH:mm:SS"];
        NSDate *now = [[[NSDate alloc] init] autorelease];
        theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];

        NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Default Album"];

        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
           [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];

        NSString *videopath= [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mov",documentsDirectory,theDate]] autorelease];

        BOOL success = [videoData writeToFile:videopath atomically:NO];

        NSLog(@"Successs:::: %@", success ? @"YES" : @"NO");
        NSLog(@"video path --> %@",videopath);
    }
}
```

Video Uploading ::

**`videoData`** is getting from `videoData = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL] retain];`

```
- (void)uploadVideo
{
    NSData *imageData = videoData;

    NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", UploadVideoService];
    NSLog(@"url=== %@", urlString);

    request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    /*  body of the post */

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //Video Name with Date-Time
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm:ssa"];
    NSString *currDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"video-%@.mov\"\r\n", currDate];
    NSLog(@"String name::  %@",str);

    [dateFormat release];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:str] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"result from webservice:::--> %@", returnString);

    [returnString release];
}
```

Hope, it'll help you.

Thanks.

Comment: it is getting crashed.

Comment: where it is crashing ?

Comment: can you provide me any example tutorial.

Comment: My code for recording video & upload it on server via device recording

Comment: can you please debug it & tell me on which line it is crashing ??

Comment: provisioning profiles are not valid it is possible to debug without valid developer profile. It may be because of apple server down issue.

Comment: yea. It's issue regarding your provisioning profile, by which you are running application in device.

Comment: what i can tell you is all that when i select the video file from gallery in device the file get compressed and after that when try to upload it get crashed but can't tell where. but as far i understood that after compressing the file issue is in posting only.

Comment: can you check my code what i posted in question may be there will be some error because that is posting but in bytes may be easy to find for you.